# Prolog for beginners about logic and syntax

Tags: prolog

I have this **question :**

I need to create a paradict "rightGuesses" which will get 3 arguments, each one of them is a list of letters,

1. The list of guessed letters
2. The word i have to guess
3. The letters that where guessed so far.

For example :

```
rightGuesses([n,o,p,q], [p,r,o,l,o,g], Ans).
```

will give us

```
Ans = [p, -, o, -, o, -].
```

I made:

```
rightGuesses([],T2,[ANS])  
rightGuesses([A|T1],T2,[ANS]):-
   (member(A,T2))=\=true,
   rightGuesses(T1,T2,[ _ |'-']).
rightGuesses([A|T1],T2,[ANS]):-
   member(A,T2),
   rightGuesses(T1,T2,[ _ |A]).
```

But I get :

> `ERROR: c:/users/leonid/desktop/file3.pl:5:0: Syntax error: Operator expected Warning: c:/users/leonid/desktop/file3.pl:6:`

When I try to compile it what is my problem, and is there is a better way to do it ?

Comment: @Amith: Your edit is not very helpful, you did not remove `<br>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after `rightGuesses([],T2,[ANS])` you miss a dot. I can't spot other syntax errors, but you have a 'semantic' one: this doesnt' make sense: `(member(A,T2))=\=true`, use `\+member(A,T2)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the errors observed by @CapelliC, there are many more errors. Like the `[_|'-']` and much more.

The first observation is that the second and third argument are lists of same length. And in fact, each element corresponds to the element at the same position in the other list. So we have a relation for each letter: `guesses_letter_sofar/3`:

```
guesses_letter_sofar(Xs, C, -) :-
   maplist(dif(C), Xs).
guesses_letter_sofar(Xs, C, C) :-
   member(C, Xs).
```

This can be more compactly expressed using [`all//1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971037/prolog-removing-unique-elements-only/21994498#21994498) as:

```
guesses_letter_sofar(Xs, C, S) :-
   phrase(( all(dif(C)), ({S=(-)}|[C],{S=C}) ).
```

Now given that, your relation is:

```
rightGuesses(Guesses, Word, Sofars) :-
   maplist(guesses_letter_sofar(Guesses), Word, Sofars).
```

Or, more verbosely:

```
rightGuesses(_Guesses, [], []).
rightGuesses(Guesses, [C|Cs], [Sofar|Sofars]) :-
   guesses_letter_sofar(Guesses, C, Sofar),
   rightGuesses(Guesses, Cs, Sofars).
```