# Prolog removing unique elements only

Tags: list, prolog

I want to return a list that removes all unique elements for example

```
remUniqueVals([1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,6],Q).   
Q = [1,1,2,2,4,4,6,6,6].
```

My problem is that currently I have code that returns

```
remUniqueVals([1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,6],Q).  
Q = [1, 2, 4, 6, 6].
```

So that only the first instance of these non-unique values are returned.
Here is my code:

```
remUniqueVals([], []).  
remUniqueVals([Q1|RestQ],[Q1|Xs]) :-        
   member(Q1,RestQ),  
   remUniqueVals(RestQ,Xs).  
remUniqueVals([Q1|RestQ],Xs) :-  
   remove(Q1,[Q1|RestQ], NewQ),  
   remUniqueVals(NewQ,Xs).
```

I can see that `member(Q1,RestQ)` fails when it checks 1,2,4 the second time because they are now no longer in the list and so removes them. I'd like some helping solving this problem, my thoughts are to check `member(Q1, PreviousQ)`, where this is the elements already in the final `Q`. Not sure how to go about implementing that though any help would be appreciated.

Update:

Ok so thanks for the suggestions I ended up going with this in the end:

```
remUniqueVals(_,[], []).  
remUniqueVals(_,[Q1|RestQ],[Q1|Xs]) :-        
   member(Q1,RestQ), 
   remUniqueVals(Q1,RestQ,Xs).  
remUniqueVals(PrevQ,[Q1|RestQ],[Q1|Xs]) :-        
   Q1 = PrevQ, 
   remUniqueVals(PrevQ,RestQ,Xs).  
remUniqueVals(PrevQ,[_|RestQ],Xs) :-  
   remUniqueVals(PrevQ,RestQ,Xs). 

remUniqueVals(0,[4,1,1,3,2,2,5,5],Q).
Q = [1, 1, 2, 2, 5, 5].

remUniqueVals(0, [A,B,C], [1,1]).
A = 1,
B = 1,
C = 1.
```

Comment: I suspect you are getting more than one answer. At least, you have three times the six....

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean… The three 6's aren't the same thing. To put it into context I'm looking at tuples so for example the above could be [[a,6],[b,6],[c,6]]. I would like to remove all tuples whose last element is unique.

Comment: For `remUniqueVals([6,6,6],Q)`, there will be two answers for `member(E, [6,6])` - but you do not report them.

Comment: I think my problem is not that they aren't reported it's that there are only two answers. So it checks member(6,[6,6]). (Unifies Q = [6]) Then checks member(6,[6]). (Q = [6,6]) Then checks member(6,[]). This fails and so returns Q = [6,6]. This is my problem. I would like to return Q = [6,6,6] but am not sure how to go about doing this using this approach.

Comment: Do you require that the original order of the remaining elements be maintained?

Comment: What is the meaning of the first argument of your new remUniqueVals/3?

Comment: The first argument is used to store the value of the number that came before it. I initialise it with 0 as in my problem 0 will never be in the set of numbers I'm looking to remove uniques from

Comment: In fact I don't believe it matters what it is initialised with.

Comment: @jalog3343646: In any case, your cuts are all malplaced, setting a cut after a recursive goal is practically never useful.

Comment: Yep thanks I've got rid of them now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is similar to the original solution but it collects the non-unique values in an auxiliary list and checks it to avoid removing the last one from the original:

```
remove_uniq_vals(L, R) :-
    remove_uniq_vals(L, [], R).

remove_uniq_vals([], _, []).
remove_uniq_vals([X|T], A, R) :-
    (   member(X, A)
    ->  R = [X|T1], A1 = A
    ;   member(X, T)
    ->  R = [X|T1], A1 = [X|A]
    ;   R = T1, A1 = A
    ),
    remove_uniq_vals(T, A1, T1).
```

Testing...

```
| ?- remove_uniq_vals([1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,3], Q).

Q = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,3]

(1 ms) yes
| ?- remove_uniq_vals([1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,6], Q).

Q = [1,1,2,2,4,4,6,6,6]

yes
```

So the predicate works great if the first argument is an input, and it maintains the original order of the remaining elements in the list.

However, this predicate is not completely *relational* in that it will fail a case in which the first argument is an uninstantiated list of a known number of elements and the second argument is a list of a different fixed number of elements. So something like this will work:

```
| ?- remove_uniq_vals([A,B,C], L).

B = A
C = A
L = [A,A,A]

(1 ms) yes
```

But something like the following fails:

```
| ?- remove_uniq_vals([A,B,C], [1,1]).

no
```

Answer (score 6):

Prolog rules are read independently of each other, so you need one rule for the case where the element is unique and one where it is not. Provided the order of the elements is not relevant, you might use:

```
?- remUniqueVals([A,B,C], [1,1]).
   A = 1, B = 1, dif(1,C)
;  A = 1, C = 1, dif(1,B)
;  B = 1, C = 1, dif(A,1)
;  false.

?- remUniqueVals([1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,6],Q).
   Q = [1,1,2,2,4,4,6,6,6]
;  false.

remUniqueVals([], []).
remUniqueVals([Q1|RestQ],[Q1|Xs0]) :-
   memberd(Q1, RestQ),
   phrase(delall(Q1, RestQ, NewQ), Xs0, Xs),
   remUniqueVals(NewQ, Xs).
remUniqueVals([Q1|RestQ],Xs) :-
   maplist(dif(Q1), RestQ),
   remUniqueVals(RestQ,Xs).

memberd(X, [X|_Xs]).
memberd(X, [Y|Xs]) :-
   dif(X,Y),
   memberd(X, Xs).

delall(_X, [], []) --> [].
delall(X, [X|Xs], Ys) -->
   [X],
   delall(X, Xs, Ys).
delall(X, [Y|Xs], [Y|Ys]) -->
   {dif(X,Y)},
   delall(X, Xs, Ys).
```

Here is an alternate definition for `memberd/2` which might be more efficient using `if_/3`:

```
memberd(E, [X|Xs]) :-
   if_(E = X, true, memberd(E, Xs) ).
```

Comment: Ok thanks! Looks like it might do the trick I'll take some time to look over and understand it all first.

Answer (score 5):

This is another pure, relational solution inspired by @CapelliC's solution. This one now retains the order of the duplicates. What is interesting to see is how the implicit quantification happening in @CapelliC's solution now has to be done explicitly.

The biggest advantage of having a pure, relational definition is that noes are noes. And ayes are ayes. That is: You do not have to worry whether or not the answer you get happens to be correct or not. It is correct (or incorrect —  but it is not partially correct). Non-relational solutions can often be cleansed by producing `instantiation_error` in case the method fails. But as you can verify yourself, both have "forgotten" such tests thereby preparing a nice habitat for bugs. A safe test for those other solutions would have been `ground(Xs)` or `ground(Xs), acyclic_term(Xs)` but much too often this is considered too restricted.

```
remUniqueVals2(Xs, Ys) :-
   tfilter(list_withduplicate_truth(Xs),Xs,Ys).

list_withduplicate_truth(L, E, Truth) :-
   phrase(
      (  all(dif(E)),
         (  {Truth = false}
         |  [E],
            all(dif(E)),
            (   {Truth = false}
            |   {Truth = true},
                [E],
                ...
            )
         )
      ),  L).

all(_) --> [].
all(P_1) -->
   [E],
   {call(P_1,E)},
   all(P_1).

... --> [] | [_], ... .

tfilter(     _, [], []).
tfilter(TFilter_2, [E|Es], Fs0) :-
   call(TFilter_2,E,Truth),
   (  Truth = false,
      Fs0 = Fs
   ;  Truth = true,
      Fs0 = [E|Fs]
   ),
   tfilter(TFilter_2, Es, Fs).
```

Another, more compact way using [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/772868)

```
tfilter(   _, [], []).
tfilter(TFilter_2, [E|Es], Fs0) :-
   if_(call(TFilter_2,E), Fs0 = [E|Fs], Fs0 = Fs ),
   tfilter(TFilter_2, Es, Fs).
```

Comment: Thanks for this (+1). This is an innocent enough sounding predicate, but seems particularly challenging for a pure, relational solution.

Comment: @mbratch: What about purifying your approach? (Make a new, separate answer).

Comment: I've been looking at it in little bits and pieces of time I can spend on it. After fooling with a couple of failed notions, it seems pretty challenging at the moment... :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a purified version of @mbratch's solution. It uses a reïfied version of `member/2` which is free of redundant answers like for `member(X,[a,a])`.

```
memberd_truth_dcg(X, Xs, Truth) :-
   phrase(( all(dif(X)), ( [X], {Truth = true}, ... | {Truth = false} ) ), Xs).
```

A slightly generalized version which only requires to have a list prefix, but not a list:

```
memberd_truth(_X, [], false).
memberd_truth(X, [X|_], true).
memberd_truth(X, [Y|Ys], Truth) :-
   dif(X,Y),
   memberd_truth(X, Ys, Truth).
```

The variables are named in the same manner as in @mbratch's solution:

```
remove_uniq_valsBR(L, R) :-
   remove_uniq_valsBR(L, [], R).

remove_uniq_valsBR([], _, []).
remove_uniq_valsBR([X|T], A, R) :-
    memberd_truth(X, A, MemT1),
    (  MemT1 = true,
       R = [X|T1], A1 = A
    ;  MemT1 = false,
       memberd_truth(X, T, MemT2),
       (  MemT2 = true,
          R = [X|T1], A1 = [X|A]
       ;  MemT2 = false,
          R = T1, A1 = A
       )
    ),
    remove_uniq_valsBR(T, A1, T1).
```

More compactly using [`if/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/772868):

```
remove_uniq_valsBR([], _, []).
remove_uniq_valsBR([X|T], A, R) :-
    if_( memberd_truth(X, A),
       ( R = [X|T1], A1 = A ),
       if_( memberd_truth(X, T),
          ( R = [X|T1], A1 = [X|A] ),
          ( R = T1, A1 = A ) ) )
    ),
    remove_uniq_valsBR(T, A1, T1).
```

What I do not like is the many redundant `dif/2` constraints. I hoped this version would have less of them:

```
?- length(L,_),remove_uniq_valsBR(L,L).
   L = []
;  L = [_A,_A]
;  L = [_A,_A,_A]
;  L = [_A,_A,_A,_A]
;  L = [_A,_A,_B,_B], dif(_B,_A)
;  L = [_A,_B,_A,_B],
   dif(_A,_B), dif(_B,_A), dif(_B,_A), dif(_A,_B)
;  ... .
```

Of course it is possible to check whether or not a `dif/2` is already present, but I'd prefer a version where there are fewer `dif/2` goals posted right from the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

Preserve [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity)! Based on [`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915), [`(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29708684/4609915), and [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)   [`tpartition/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915) we define:

```
remUniqueValues([], []).
remUniqueValues([X|Xs1], Ys1) :-
   tpartition(=(X), Xs1, Eqs, Xs0),
   if_(Eqs = [],
       Ys1 = Ys0,
       append([X|Eqs], Ys0, Ys1)),
   remUniqueValues(Xs0, Ys0).
```

Let's see it in action!

```
?- remUniqueValues([A,B,C], [1,1]).
       A=1 ,     B=1 , dif(C,1)
;      A=1 , dif(B,1),     C=1
;  dif(A,1),     B=1 ,     C=1
;  false.

?- remUniqueValues([1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,6,6,6], Vs).
Vs = [1,1,2,2,4,4,6,6,6].                   % succeeds deterministically
```

Comment: could you perhaps edit the logical-purity tag info with the explanation of what this "logical purity" means, because, as it is written right now (*"programs using only Horn clauses"*) I don't see how `if_/3` qualifies, using as much as it is the cut, and the various meta-logical (what's the proper terminology? `var/1` and such) predicates, i.e. the low-level stuff. I get it that it achieves some "pure" effect, I'd just like to see it explicated so I (and presumably others) don't have to guess. Would appreciate it very much. -- So, how does `if_/3` qualify as logically pure?

Comment: @WillNess: It would be best if you ask a question about this.

Answer (score 2):

a solution based on 3 builtins:

```
remUniqueVals(Es, NUs) :-
    findall(E, (select(E, Es, R), memberchk(E, R)), NUs).
```

can be read as

> find all elements that still appear in list after have been selected

Comment: Nice, but non-relational. E.g., fails for `remUniqueValsCC([A,B],[]).`