# Prolog: true / false output of member predicate?

Tags: prolog, member

I am wondering why the `member/2` predicate of Prolog delivers multiple alternatives (via backtracking?!), if true was already unified for the output.

For example `member(1, [1,2,3]).` delivers the following output:

```
true ;
false.
```

Why does `member` return false after it already found out that the atom `1` is indeed a member of the list `[1,2,3]`?

Even more confusing to me is the following output:

```
?- member(1, [1,2,3,1]).
true ;
true.
```

Comment: what Prolog implementation are you using?

Comment: I'm using Swi-Prolog.

Comment: An improvement is [`memberd/2`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21971885/772868).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first example, you ask it to prove `member(1,[1,2,3]).`; since it can, it reports `true`.  When you enter `;`, you are asking to find another way to prove that query; since it cannot, it reports `false`.

In the second case, the first `true` is because it found one of the `1`'s in the list; the second is because it found the second.  If you had hit `;` again, it would have come back with `false`, as it had no other ways to prove the query.  (Note: As @WillNess points out, you don't actually get the chance to hit `;` again; this is probably due to the implementation of `member` being such that Prolog knows there are no remaining alternatives.  If the list did not end with a 1, you would be able to hit `;` again.)