# Prolog: having true and false value

Tags: list, prolog

I am learning to use SWI Prolog, and I am learning to use lists. A small exercise is to check if an element is in a list. Here's what I got:

```
member(X,[X|_]).
member(X,[_|T]):-member[X|T].
```

The first case goes as intended:

```
?- member(a,[b,a]).
true.
```

But the second doesn't, as some backtracking seems to appear:

```
?- member(a,[a,b]).
true ;
false.
```

How could I prevent this from happening, i.e. to get Prolog return me only *true*? (I don't want to ignore false.)

Comment: The first `true` means it succeed. The `false` means that when you asked it to find more solutions with `;` it found no more, so it came back `false` at that point. Normal Prolog behavior. Also, `member/2` is a standard Prolog predicate. You should name yours something else. The standard predicate has the same behavior that you show.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`member/2` is a standard Prolog predicate. You should name yours something else. The standard predicate has the same behavior that you show.

When you query:

```
?- member(a, [a,b]).
true ;
false.
```

Prolog finds that `a` matches the first element and succeeds. There's more in the list to check so it prompts you for more. Pressing `;` says "yes, please, check for more". When it does, it finds no more `a` members so then yields `false` (in GNU Prolog, it would say `no`).

You can make it go away by either:

- Not pressing `;` but press Enter instead, OR
- Use `once/1`: `once(member(a, [a,b]))`, OR
- You can change your predicate to include a cut in the first clause, but this is a bad idea since then it won't work in the general case: `member(X, [a,b])` will only return `X = a` and then stop.

Answer (score 4):

Using [`memberd/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21971885) based on `library(reif)` available for [SICStus](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/reif.pl)|[SWI](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/swi/reif.pl), you get determinism in many cases:

```
?- memberd(a, [a,b]).
   true.
?- memberd(a, [a,a]).
   true.
?- memberd(a, [a,X]).
   true.
?- memberd(a, [a|Xs]).
   true.
```

Compare this to `member/2`:

```
?- member(a, [a,b]).
   true
;  false.              % leftover choicepoint
?- member(a, [a,a]).
   true
;  true.               % redundant solution
?- member(a, [a,X]).
  true
; X = a.               % redundant solution
?- member(a, [a|Xs]).
   true
;  Xs = [a|_A]         % redundant answer
;  Xs = [_A, a|_B]     % redundant answer
;  Xs = [_A, _B, a|_C] % redundant answer
;  ... .
```

And still the implementation of `memberd/2` produces different answers, when necessary

```
?- memberd(a, [X,Y]).
   X = a
;  Y = a, dif(X, a)
;  false.
```

Even in this case, `memberd/2` avoids the redundancy of `member/2`:

```
?- member(a, [X,Y]).
   X = a
;  Y = a.        % partially redundant
```

These two answers are partially redundant: `X = a, Y = a` is described by both!

```
?- member(a, [X,Y]), X = a, Y = a.
   X = Y, Y = a
;  X = Y, Y = a.    % redundant solution
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that any query will unify with both clauses since `member(X,[X|_])` unifies with `member(X,[_|T])`. You need mutually exclusive clauses. Since the prolog cut will break reversibility (as stated before), there is another option:

```
member(X,[X|_]).
member(X,[Y|T]):- X \== Y, member[X|T].
```

Comment: There is a good idea here, but you need `dif/2` in place of `(\==)/2`! And some brackets etc.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is good but maybe it is important to add that `member/2` is in textbooks with this implementation exactly and because it uses pattern matchin and unification it can do more interesting things...

```
?- member(a(X), [a(1), b(2), c(3), a(4), b(5), a(6)]).
X = 1 ;
X = 4 ;
X = 6.
```

There is also `memberchk/2` which is for testing for membership only. The other answer also explain how to implement.

It seems the two are on purpose not the same (why make both otherwise?)