# Does an element exists in a list of lists?

Tags: list, prolog, member

I want to find if a given element exists in a list of lists. I am only getting true if the element exists somewhere is the first list of lists.

Any advice?

```
memberlist(X,[[X|T1]|T2]).
memberlist(X,[[H|T1]|T2]) :-
  memberlist(X,[T1|T2]).
```

Comment: `member(Xs, Xss), member(X, Xs)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `[[H|T1]|T2]` only matches given the *first* list has *at least* one element. Indeed: `[[],[1,4],[2,5]]` for instance does *not* unify with `[[H|T1]|T2]`.

So you can solve the problem by adding a clause:

```
memberlist(X,[[]|T2]) :-
    memberlist(X,T2).
```

thus we obtain:

```
memberlist(X,[[X|_]|_]).
memberlist(X,[[H|T1]|T2]) :-
    memberlist(X,[T1|T2]).
memberlist(X,[[]|T2]) :-
    memberlist(X,T2).
```

the first clause also uses the underscores to specify that we are "not interested" in these variables. This is common for Prolog programs (probably the interpreter warned that `T1` and `T2` were mentioned only once).

So in case the first list is exhausted, we simply move to the next list.

Your predicate does a lot of "packing" and "unpacking". Furthermore we can make use of the `member/2` builtin. So we can rewrite it:

```
memberlist(X,[H|_]) :-
    member(X,H).
memberlist(X,[_|T2]) :-
  memberlist(X,T2).
```

Comment: Missed it a little bit there.Greetings :)

Comment: Still too complex

Comment: @false can you provide something less complex?

Comment: @Alator: See my answer

Answer (score 10):

```
memberlists(X, Xss) :-
   member(Xs, Xss),
   member(X, Xs).
```

Similar to `member/2`, this produces many redundant answers like:

```
?- memberlists(X, [[a,a],[a],[a]]).
   X = a
;  X = a  % redundant
;  X = a  % redundant
;  X = a. % redundant
```

Alternatively, you might want to use [`memberd/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21971885) in place of `member/2`.

```
memberlists2(X, Xss) :-
   memberd(Xs, Xss),
   memberd(X, Xs).

?- memberlists2(X, [[a,a],[a],[a]]).
   X = a
;  X = a   % redundant
;  false.
```

This is much better, but still does not remove all redundant answers.

For a solution that removes all such redundancies a bounty has been set.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a more compact version of the very nice 2nd solution by @user27815 (s(0) for both solutions). There is actually no need to use reification in the predicate member_lists/2 as is done in member_lists_t/3. In fact using [memberd_t/3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/6101159) as first argument of [if_/3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/6101159) is sufficient for termination after finding the first solution. Hence the relation can be expressed as a single rule with a single goal like so:

```
member_lists(X,[H|T]) :-
  if_(memberd_t(X,H),true,member_lists(X,T)).
```

The query

```
   ?- member_lists(X,[[a,a],[a]]).
X = a ? ;
no
```

is only producing a single solution. The query

```
   ?- member_lists(X,[[X|_]|_]).

true
```

is terminating deterministically.

Comment: Clearly the best solution. However, isn't it a bit odd that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43426864/772868) looks so much simper - yet it is so inefficient? Maybe that should go into a further question & bounty.

Comment: @false: Yes, it's odd indeed. Richard O'Keefe writes in the introductory chapter of "The Craft of Prolog" that one of the books main themes is "elegance is not optional". I find that to be a very accurate observation. Yet this seems to be a counterexample. At least according to his first interpretation of the statement (efficiency). However, in terms of maintainability (2nd interpretation) it still applies: In your post I can see at first glimpse what's going on. In mine... Well, if I was not familiar with reification...

Comment: At least your solution is really pure & efficient! Maybe some higher-order [tag:meta-predicate] may cover the abstraction...

Answer (score 7):

What about this?

```
list([])     --> [].
list([L|Ls]) --> [L], list(Ls).

concatenation([]) --> [].
concatenation([List|Lists]) -->
   list(List),
   concatenation(Lists).

memberd(X, [X|_Xs]).
memberd(X, [Y|Xs]) :-
   dif(X,Y),
   memberd(X, Xs).

memberlists(X, Lists):-
   phrase(concatenation(Lists),List),
   memberd(X,List).
```

Comment: Definitely a pure, good solution. But is it really necessary to convert the entire list first? That's not a stated requirement.

Comment: (Do not modify your answer if you want to submit another solution, instead use a separate answer!)

Comment: Here is a case where your solution does not terminate, but one might even expect that it succeeds deterministically: `memberlists(X,[[X|_]|_])`. Compare this to `memberd(X,[X|_])` which also succeeds and terminates.

Answer (score 6):

With if_/3:

```
memberd_t(_,[],false).
memberd_t(X,[Y|Ys],Truth) :-
 if_(X=Y, Truth=true, memberd_t(X,Ys,Truth)).

member_lists_t(_,[],false).
member_lists_t(X,[H|T],Truth):-
 if_(memberd_t(X,H),Truth=true,member_lists_t(X,T,Truth)).

member_lists(X,Lists):-
 member_lists_t(X,Lists,true).
```

Comment: You mean `memberd_t/3` in place of `memberd/3`?

Comment: And no `_t` for `member_lists_t/3`.

Comment: See `library(reif)` for [SICStus](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/reif.pl)|[SWI](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/swi/reif.pl).

Comment: It should be memberd_t I guess, but still member_lists_t? as that is called in if_/3?

Comment: No need for reification in `member_lists/2`!

Comment: Currently succeeds for `member_lists(a,[[b,c]])`

Comment: Doh! I should check not just blindly edit. I have changed it, but it still has memberd_t ...

Comment: and member_lists_t

Comment: You really could leave out member_lists_t altogether.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my approach using `sort/2` and `flat/2` that flatten a list only one level:

```
memberlists(X, Xss) :- Xss = [_|_], 
                       flat(Xss, FL), 
                       sort(FL, OutL), 
                       memberd(X, OutL).

memberd(X, [X|_Xs]).
memberd(X, [Y|Xs]) :-
   dif(X,Y),
   memberd(X, Xs).                       

flat([],[]).
flat([H|T],R) :- H = [_|_], flat(T,T1), append(H,T1,R).
```

Testcases:

```
 ?- memberlists(X,[[a,A]]), A = a.
X = A, A = a ;
false.

?- memberlists(X,[[a]|Xs]), Xs = [_|_].
Xs = [[X]] ;
X = a,
Xs = [[_G13004]],
dif(a, _G13004) ;
Xs = [[X, _G12784]] .

?- memberlists(X,[[a,a],[Y],[b]]).
X = Y ;
X = a,
dif(a, Y) ;
X = b,
dif(b, Y) ;
false.

?- memberlists(X,[[a,a],[a],[a]]).
X = a ;
false.

?- memberlists(X,[[[a,a],[a],[a]]]).
X = [a] ;
X = [a, a] ;
false.

?- memberlists(X,[L]).
L = [X] ;
L = [X, _G12710] ;
L = [_G12923, X],
dif(X, _G12923) ;
L = [X, _G12710, _G12716] ;
L = [_G12935, X, _G12941],
dif(X, _G12935) . (and goes on...)

?- memberlists(X,L).
L = [[X]]
L = [[X, _G12704]] ;
L = [[_G12920, X]],
dif(X, _G12920) ;
L = [[X, _G12704, _G12710]] ;
L = [[_G12932, X, _G12938]],
dif(X, _G12932) ;
L = [[_G13018, _G13021, X]],
dif(X, _G13021),
dif(X, _G13018) ;
L = [[X, _G12704, _G12710, _G12716]] . (and goes on...)
```

Comment: Incorrectly fails for `memberlists(X,[[a]|Xs]), Xs = [_|_].` It should succeed (or loop).

Comment: Produced two answers for `memberlists(X,[[a,A]]), A = a.` So there are still redundant solutions.

Comment: @false, problems solved using memberd/2 see the updated answer,  any advice well accepted!!

Comment: `memberlists(X,[[X|_]|_]).` could succeed deterministically

Answer (score -3):

The answer to the original question is as follows:

```
memberlist(X, [X| _]) :- !.
memberlist(X, [[A|B]|_]) :-
    memberlist(X,[A|B]), !.
memberlist(X, [_ | Rest]) :-
    memberlist(X, Rest).
```

This solution will only give one result when X is given a value in the query. With a little more work this can be changed to a tail recursive algorithm. But the question seems to expanded to look for a way to have this return the set of singleton elements that are members of all the embedded lists.

The solution is to flatten the lists into a single list and then turn the list into a set.

The code for flatten from cs.uni-potsdam.de is:

```
flatten(List, Flat) :-
    flatten(List, Flat, []).

flatten([], Res, Res) :- !.
flatten([Head|Tail], Res, Cont) :-
        !,
        flatten(Head, Res, Cont1),
        flatten(Tail, Cont1, Cont).
flatten(Term, [Term|Cont], Cont).
```

The code for turning a list to set (from http://www.cs.oswego.edu/~odendahl/coursework/notes/prolog/synopsis/)

```
member(X,[X|_]).
member(X,[_|Y]) :- member(X,Y).

make_set([],[]).
make_set(X,Y) :- setof(Z,member(Z,X),Y).
```

So the finally piece is:

```
setofmembers(NestedLists, Set) :-
    flatten(NestedLists,Flat),
    make_set(Flat,Set).

memberlist2(X,Lists) :-
    setofmembers(Lists,Set),
    member(X,Set).
```

Of course this is not totally satisfactory because it is not tail recursive and it not very efficient. But coming up with an efficient tail recursive solution would take me a couple hours and I have to mow the lawn.

Comment: The predicate ```memberlist(X,L)``` is supposed to to be true exactly if ```L``` is a list and ```X``` is member of one of the elements of ```L```. Therefore, ```memberlist(X,[a]).``` should fail but your implementation does not.

Comment: Btw ```a``` might be covered as underspecified, but it also holds for ```memberlist(X,[[]]).```:  a list of an empty list contains nothing, but the implementation claims that the empty list contains the empty list.