# Swi-Prolog Select List from List of Lists

Tags: prolog

Hello I'm doing a project on prolog and still grasping with the language.
I currently have a list of lists, in which the sublists have coordinates.

My aim is to select the sublist with a certain coordinate X and then to cut that list from it's first element up to X. (only one list)

I thought that at first the problem would to be to select the sublist with member. So I tried to do so.

```
sublist([],_, []).
sublist([H|R],Pos, [H|Aux]) :-
    member(Pos,H), !,
    sublist(R,Pos, Aux).
sublist([H|R],Pos, Aux) :-
    sublist(R,Pos,Aux).
```

This doesn't work:

```
?- sublist([[(1,2),(1,3),(3,5)],[(1,5),(1,2)]], (1,5), X).
X = [].
```

What I wanted for this first stage was something like:

```
?- sublist([[(1,2),(1,3),(3,5)],[(1,5),(1,2)]], (1,5), X).
X = [(1,5),(1,2)].
```

(afterwards, when I have the sublist selected I planned on doing a similar thing in which I add elements to an empty list until the element equals X).

So that the end result would be:

```
?- sublist([[(1,2),(1,3),(3,5)],[(1,5),(1,2)]], (1,5), X).
X = [(1,5)].
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm still learning to think in Prolog so I apologize for obvious logic mistakes.

Comment: Related (i.e., same homework question): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50155722/print-a-list-inside-a-nested-list-that-contains-an-element

Comment: Also, my Prolog spits out warnings, including: `Clauses of sublist/3 are not together in the source-file ... Current predicate: sulist/3`. You have a typo you need to fix.

Comment: Fixed! Though the typo isn't the source of the problem (I translated from my code and missed it). Checking the link you sent, thanks!

Comment: The link sent gave me the general idea to make this work, thanks and sorry for the duplicate!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly:

```
sublist(L, Elem, M) :-
    member(M, L),
    member(Elem, M).
```

(`L` contains a list `M`, which contains and element `Elem`)

gives that result:

```
?- sublist([[(1,2),(1,3),(3,5)],[(1,5),(1,2)]], (1,5), X).
X = [(1, 5),  (1, 2)] ;
false.
```