# Prolog: Say how Prolog responds to the inquiry and draw a search tree for it ?- member(2, [2, a, X])

Tags: prolog

How will Prolog respond to the following inquiry? Draw a search tree for the inquiry, too.

```
?- member(2, [2, a, X]).
```

---

So first of all, what does this inquiry mean?

Let's take another more clear example:

```
?-  member(vincent,[yolanda,trudy,vincent,jules]).
```

Prolog will check if `vincent` is in the list. It checks one by one, so it will first compare `vincent` and `yolanda`. No match, now recursive rule aka go to second clause. Now it looks like that:

```
?-  member(vincent,[trudy,vincent,jules]).
```

`vincent` and `trudy`, no match. Recursive rule:

```
?-  member(vincent,[vincent,jules]).
```

`vincent` and `vincent`, match! So return `true`.

---

Back to our example. Prolog will immediately return `true` as `2` is in the list (namely the head of it).

But how will the search tree look like? I really have no idea and I'm scared they will ask me to draw a search tree in the test...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That query means

> For which `X` is 2 an element of the list `[2, a, X]`?

Well, let's see how Prolog answers this:

```
?- member(2, [2, a, X]).
   true
;  X = 2.
```

The first **answer** we get is `true` which is the empty answer substitution. It means here that 2 is a member of that list for *any* `X`.  Really any!  Can this be true?

```
?- X = any, member(2, [2, a, X]).
   X = any
;  false.                % that is no solution
```

It's even true for `any`!

Now back to the original query: The second answer is a simple solution `X = 2`.  So Prolog tells us that also 2 might be such an element. Alas, we already know that, for we know that this holds for any term. And thus also 2.  Therefore, the second answer is **redundant**.

You can avoid many such redundancies by using [`memberd/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21971885) instead!

---

As for the search tree, `member/2` always visits the entire list. One solution after the other. So the search tree only depends on the number of elements in the list.